# Custom struct with casting to another type in C#

Tags: c#

I have a struct currently that i can cast to another type like this:

```
    public static implicit operator Vector2(Complex a)
    {
        return new Vector2(a.Real,a.Imaginary);
    }
```

At the moment how ever this is allowed automatically:

```
Vector2 a = new Complex(b,c); //valid
```

But i would prefer it did not automatically allow this. But rather only allow:

```
Vector2 a = (Vector2) new Complex(b,c);
```

How can i have a restricted casting with this kinda behaviour for my struct the same way floats casting to ints work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `implicit` to `explicit`:

```
public static explicit operator Vector2(Complex a)
```

The `implicit` part tells the compiler that it can do it without the code specifying the conversion. See the [Microsoft documentation for user-defined operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) for more details.